# Matlab Editor - show tabs and whitespace characters

Tags: matlab

I've been writing a lot of code in Matlab 2012a recently, and I'm wondering if there's some way to show whitespace characters (tabs, spaces, etc.) like in Notepad++ or Sublime Text.

I've been Googling around and did a search on SO, but the internet seems oddly quiet.

Thanks!

Comment: May I know, why you need those. M-Scripting doesn't require any indentation rules.

Comment: That's a fair question. Honestly? I'm just being a little anal. As I spend more time in an IDE I like to have more control. I'm the same way with Java which also doesn't have any indentation rules, but fortunately Eclipse lets me show whitespace, has an auto-indent function, and let's me color things the way I like :) I like to entertain nit-picky preferences like this sometimes based on the proposition, "Every good work of software starts by scratching a developer's personal itch" (CatB)

Comment: Since the editor like all of the Matlab GUI is implemented in Java and Matlab allows to interact with Java objects including those making up the GUI, it might be possible to achieve this through a hack – provided the basic functionality of the underlying compiled Java code allows for this. A good starting point would be http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-the-matlab-editor/

Comment: Btw., I'm anal about whitespace, too, but I think the Matlab editor does a good job in guiding you to decent indentation. If you ever get lost though, Ctrl-I on a selected block of code provides an easy way to correct its indentation.

Comment: I'll add another reason: I use tabs and my collaborators use spaces for indentation. Diff-ing and version control get much more difficult if most of the changes are whitespace, so I'd like to see in the editor which lines have which kind of indentation and keep it consistent.

Comment: Another reason: I inherited a (poorly written) function which searched for a keyword *not* being commented out by checking whether the keyword started at position 1 in a line.  A random whitespace caused this search to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't think you can do this in the MATLAB editor, you can choose to use a different editor as your default. Under Preferences go to Editor/Debugger, and select "Text Editor" rather than "MATLAB Editor" (you need to supply the full path).

If this is set, then `.m` files etc. opened from within MATLAB should open in your preferred editor, not the MATLAB editor.

Comment: I'm really inclined to accept this answer, but before I do--I'm working in Simulink. This pops up my scripts in my external editor of choice. I don't suppose you know how to make this work when dealing with Simulink user-defined functions, do you? (these still pop up the matlab default editor)

Comment: I think there's an embedded MATLAB/MATLAB function editor that is used in some cases in Simulink - it's slightly different from the standard editor, and there doesn't seem to an easy way to change that setup.

Comment: I did some digging to see if there's something that I'm missing, but I think that this is probably the best answer I'm going to get